# Can service principal with owner access to a subscription access the active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an azure service principal with owner access that is able to add contributors at the resource or resource group level.
But when i use the same service principal to access Azure AD it fails and throws a 403 forbidden error.
Is it possible that a service principal with owner access to a subscription fails to access azure ad in the same subscription?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how you're trying to access Azure AD using this service principal? Please share your code which is leading to 403 error you mention.

Comment: Ok.so i have a subscription,tenant,client secret and appid.so using this to create token to call the get users.i am using microsoft graph api 1.0.

Comment: This sp has owner access in this subscription.i have used this to add users as contributors to resources or at even resoirce group level.same sp isnt allowing me to query ad users.does an sp with owner access by default have access to azure ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscription is under the azure ad tenant, the owner role is an RBAC role which manages the resources in the subscription, not the azure ad tenant.

For more details about the roles, refer to [Classic subscription administrator roles, Azure RBAC roles, and Azure AD administrator roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles).

If you want to fix the error to call the Microsoft graph to [list users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs)/[get a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) in the tenant, navigate to your AD App in the `App registrations` in the prortal -> `API permissions` -> `Add a permission` -> select `Microsoft Graph` -> `Application permissions` -> `User.Read.All` -> click `Add permissions` -> click `Grant admin consent for xxx`, then it will work.

[image]

[image]